# Generate TIE cells with Yosys?

Tags: verilog, yosys

I am using [Yosys](http://www.clifford.at/yosys/) to synthesise my RTL design which includes a couple of literal constants, such as tied output ports as in the following code:

```
module my_module (
    input a,
    input b,
    output c,
    output d);

    assign c = a & b;
    assign d = 1'b1;
endmodule
```

In this case, output `d` will obviously always be a logical one. The flow I am using includes the `abc -liberty my_stdcells.lib` call to map the combinatorial logic to the standard cells provided by the library, followed by the `clean` and `write_verilog` calls.

The cell library I am using also provides `TIELO` and `TIEHI` cells, but the synthesised Verilog netlist doesn't include any instances of those cells but instead still shows literal constants like in the example above.

I could probably write a script to post-process the synthesised netlist to replace these literals with `TIE*` cell instances from the library, but I am wondering if I could get Yosys to do that for me somehow, resulting in something like

```
TIEHI tiehi_d_inst(.Y(d));
```

for the `assign d = 1'b1` line in the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you are looking for is [`hilomap`](http://www.clifford.at/yosys/cmd_hilomap.html). For example, to map to `TIEHI` and `TIELO` cells with `Y` outputs use something like:

```
hilomap -hicell TIEHI Y -locell TIELO Y
```

This will create an individual `TIEHI`/`TIELO` cell for each constant bit in the design. Use the option `-singleton` to only create single `TIEHI`/`TIELO` cells with a higher fan-out.